# mixing H.264 and AV1 in a single DASH manifest?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mpeg-dash

I used the example in the ffmpeg-all man page to write an `ffmpeg` command line to build an MPEG-DASH stream with multiple encoding options from a single source file:

```
ffmpeg -i <input>.mp4 -map 0 -map 0 -map 0 -map 0 -map 0 -map 0 -map 0 -crf 23
  -c:v:0 libsvtav1 -preset:v:0 8
  -c:v:1 libsvtav1 -preset:v:1 8 -s:v:1 640x360
  -c:v:2 libsvtav1 -preset:v:2 8 -s:v:2 320x180
  -c:v:3 libx264 -b:v:3 1024k -preset:v:3 veryfast -filter:v:3 'scale=900:trunc(ow/a/2)*2'
  -c:v:4 libx264 -b:v:4 768k -preset:v:4 veryfast -filter:v:4 'scale=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2'
  -c:v:5 libx264 -b:v:5 256k -preset:v:5 veryfast -filter:v:5 'scale=480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2'
  -c:v:6 copy
  -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 128k
  -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 64k
  -c:a:2 libopus -b:a:2 128k
  -c:a:3 libopus -b:a:3 64k
  -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a"
  -f dash <output>.mpd
```

The idea here is to create a DASH stream with MPEG-4 and AV1 options for video, and Opus and AAC options for audio.

This "works", in that it does not produce an error message, and it creates a stream that can be played using `mpv`. I can select an audio or video stream explicitly using `--vid=` and/or `--aid=` options to mpv, so the muxing *seems* to work.

However, when I investigate in detail, it turns out that all the chunks are stored in `.m4s` containers, which (I believe?) is invalid for AV1 streams (those need to be in `.webm` containers). As such, the AV1 alternatives are not playable by media players that are not ffmpeg based. At any rate, whether my guess is wrong or not, I seem to be unable to play the DASH stream using things like [dash.js](https://dashjs.org/) or [VLC](https://videolan.org).

Am I doing this right? Is the `-f dash` muxer the right thing to use for this?

I looked at `DASHEncoder`, but that (at first glance) seemed to be specific to MPEG-4; ffmpeg's man page at least *mentions* WebM-DASH, so one would think that this could work.

What am I missing?